# Don't show minimized windows in overview

Tags: release-loki, pantheon, multitasking-view

Is it possible to hide minimized windows from overview or multitasking view in Loki? I have a lot of web apps and messengers in minimized state, and they make it hard to find the window I need right now.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as long as the windows are not closed but only minimized.

As a workaround, you can put these windows you do not want to see among the other to another workspace so they do not show up in the overview on your primary workspace…